# selectizeJS dropdown just have to show after 3 characters

Tags: selectize.js

In SelectizeJS, the dropdown want be show directly after an keypress. Is there a possibility to show the dropdown after 3 characters?

Comment: There is probably some kind of onChange or onKeyDown Event which displays that. You should be able to alter that function (check if length of string is >= 3) or write one to hook in there...